# regex to find all conditional statements

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements

is it possible to have a regex that will find all regex condition statements? 
This is what I have come up with so far

```
 (?:[^\\][\(]\?:.+[\)])
```

but it does not work that well, it will just go until the last bracket in the statement, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean ternary conditions?

Comment: i'm not sure what a ternary conditions is but this is what i am referring to  [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Comment: You want a regex to find all conditionals in a regex? Why?!

Comment: i need it for a program that i am writing, the program needs to test if the conditional evaluate to true or false so i want to extract it and then just apply that to the statement

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but you're in for a world of hurt if that's the only solution, and you need it to be general-purpose. What kind of inputs are you expecting? Isn't there a better way to do this than trying to parse a regular expression and evaluating chunks of it?!

Comment: @user979490: That doesn't really make sense, because conditions are only "true" or "false" at a specific location in the string. For example, if the string is `"456"`, then the condition `(?=5)` will be true in the regex `^4(?(?=5)56$|$)` and false in the regex `^(?(?=5)56$|456$)`. So you can't evaluate the condition before evaluating the rest of the regex.

Comment: I didn't know that this would be so hard to do, I thought this would be a lot easier.My end goal is to test a lot of sample inputs against some regexs to find an ideal set of inputs that test every aspect of the regex. This was the only solution I could come up with. do you guys know of any better way of accomplishing this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the general case, because the condition could contain arbitrarily nested pairs of `()`. A single Java pattern cannot handle that; it requires [a context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), whereas Java patterns can only implement regular grammars. (Well, mostly. A few bonus features, notably backreferences, allow grammars that are technically not regular, but they're still not enough to let a single pattern handle nested parentheses.)